# Clientside Scripting Language

Tags: python, browser, scripting, client-side

Is Javascript the only language that can utilise the DOM API? Is there a DOM wrapper for Python?

Comment: -1: Google searched DOM API Python, got http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html

Comment: Also, Google searched DOM wrapper Python, got http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540214/can-python-be-used-for-client-side-web-development (the first result for a Google search of "client-side python").

Comment: If you can find a client who is using [Grail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grail_(web_browser)) :)

Comment: I should have Googled first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are in-browser implementations of Python: http://www.skulpt.org/

Comment: Can you manipulate the DOM from this implementation of Python?  Not that I have any need to, but I am curious.

Comment: @JasonSperske I don't believe you can do so natively, you'd have to interact with JS for the browser interface.

Comment: It's just a wrapper on top of javascript. An interpreted language on top of an interpreted language! Don't use this if you expect any performance!

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer has support for client-side VBScript, but nobody really uses it. Javascript is an implementation of ECMAScript, by Brendan Eich at Netscape. It became the de-facto standard.

However, most languages have libraries written that can traverse an html document in the server side. In Python a common one is called Beautiful Soup.

Comment: AFAIK it's the other way around: ECMAScript is the standardization of Javascript (originally created by Brendan Eich at Netscape), after it was haphazardly re-implemented in incompatible ways by other browser vendors. Just for the record, eh.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can also use [Java Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/manipulatingDOMFromApplet.html) to manipulate the DOM.  Why you would is a question that has probably led to the inevitable lack of popularity though.